# FSharp Options And Null

Tags: f#

I am having trouble with the following F sharp function:

```
let compare (a:int option list) (b:int option list) =         
let r =
    if a.Tail = [None] && b.Tail = [None] then 
        [None]
    elif a.Tail = [None] then
        [b.Head;None]
    elif b.Tail = [None] then
        [a.Head; None]
    else
        if a=b then
            a
        else
           [None]
r
```

When I run it with the following arguments

```
compare [Some 1] [Some 0]
```

the answer is

```
[null]
```

instead of

```
[None]
```

Can somebody explain why; Thank you!

Comment: The compare, You'd better not be redefined because it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the way it is displayed but in fact the value is None.
If you try this

```
Option.isNone  ( ( compare [Some 1] [Some 0] ).[0] ) ;;
```

You get

```
val it : bool = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your `compare` function gives the right answer. The fsi printer prints `None` as `null`, which is a little misleading.

You can test that `None` is incompatible to unsafe `null` values as follows:

```
let xs = compare [Some 1] [Some 0]
let ys = [None]
let zs = [null]
let test1 = xs = ys;; // true
let test2 = xs = zs;; // error: The type 'int option' does not have 'null' as a proper value
```

BTW, your function has wrong indentation and is difficult to read. You can improve its readability using pattern-matching:

```
let compare (a:int option list) b =         
 let r =
    match a, b with
    | [_; None], [_; None] -> [None]
    | [_; None], y::_ -> [y; None]
    | x::_, [_; None] -> [x; None]
    | _ when a = b -> a
    | _ -> [None]
 r
```